# Custom text selection color in webview

Tags: javascript, android, css, pdf

**Problem:**

We want to change the color of webview textselection so that it shows the same color as user releases touch. I have done the highlight part but I cant find a great solution for changing the selection color.

**Tried mehods:**

- ::selection CSS : This only works for desktop browser not android webview.
- Manually draw the selection area in onDraw: This is quite troublesome, since we have to manage coordinates ourself.

**Note:**

I have seen many ebook reader apps(Kindle, iBooks, aldiko, Moon+Reader) have this feature but I cant really find a solution for this.

Anyone has solution for it please advise.
Thanks

[image: Moon+Reader]

Comment: I've been trying to do the same. I have no idea about touch, but for the computer I was thinking of catching the `mousedownevent` and then the `mousemove` event, and hopefully being able to catch (somehow) the pixel position of the selection using `window.getSelection()`. Have you managed to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Include a `<style>` tag before the HTML content you're displaying with the Webview.

`html_text = "<style> ::selection{ background: #3F51B5; color:#FFFFFF; } </style>
<body> YOUR_CONTENT</body>";`

Change the background and text colors accordingly, then pass it to the Webview:

`your_webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html_text, "text/html", "utf-8", null);`

Answer (score 0):

It is hardly browser-dependant. In a lot of browser is doesn't work, in the others goes this very different. The problem is the same as with the outline-on-active frame in chrome.